# Computing the probability of the union of an intersection of events

Tags: probability-theory

I have been stuck on the following problem for more than a week and neither Google, this StackExchange nor study materials from when I followed probability theory were any help. Could you please help me to find a solution to my problem?

#### Problem Statement

Consider a probabilistic universe $U$ with independent events $A..F \subseteq U$. The probability of these events $A..F$ occuring is known. We want to compute the probability of a union of an arbitrary number of intersections of an arbitrary number of events. Let's take - for example - the following statement:

$$ (A\land{}C\land{}D\land{}E) \lor (A\land{}C\land{}F) \lor (B\land{}D\land{}F) \lor (B\land{}E) $$

Then I need to compute the corresponding probability:

$$ P((A\cap{}C\cap{}D\cap{}E) \cup (A\cap{}C\cap{}F) \cup (B\cap{}D\cap{}F) \cup (B\land{}E)) = ? $$

However, since the terms of the union (the intersections) have overlapping events/sets, I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Edit: stated that the individual probabilities of the events are known

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information to get going. Is something missing? What sort of answer do you expect?

Comment: You can use $P(X \cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$ to combine terms but it will be messy.  Or you can look at the $2^5=32$ disjoint quintuple intersections (including of complements) and add up the probabilities of those in your statement, again messy

Comment: @Henry How would you approach finding all intersections to remove? Combining the first two terms is relatively easy, but how do I approach the consecutive terms?

Comment: @jbakker I would probably take the second approach: the first has 4/64 sextuple intersections (I should have said $2^6=64$), the second and third 8/64 each and the fourth 16/64, and then remove the duplicates.  You could halve the number by spotting that $A \cap C$ is really a single event here